# Como trazer todos os itens que não possuem referência com determinada tabela [SQL]

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Estou usando o NHibernate para fazer uma consulta em sql no C#, porém estou com uma duvida.

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
public class Pessoa {
   public long Id {get; set;}
   public string Nome {get; set;}
}

public class Usuario {
   public long Id { //Utiliza o id da pessoa }
   public Pessoa pessoa {get; set;}
}
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer é conseguir uma listagem das pessoas que existem, mas não estão vinculadas com o usuário, ou seja, todos as pessoas que podem se tornar um usuário.

Atualmente estou usando o seguinte código:

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<Pessoa> getPessoasSemUsuarios()
{
    var usuarios = Domain.Query(); //Lista de usuários
    var pessoas = pessoaDomain.Query(); //Lista de pessoas

    var pessoasSemUsuarios = new List<Pessoa>();

    pessoas.ToList().ForEach(pessoa =>
    {
        //Adiciona todas as pessoas que não são usuários.
        if (!usuarios.Any(x => x.Pessoa.Id == pessoa.Id))
            pessoasSemUsuarios .Add(pessoa);
    });

    return pessoasSemUsuarios ;
}
```

Obs: pensei em algo relacionado a left outer join, mas não tenho certeza, alguma ideia ?

Comment: a minha sugestão é usar left join, e onde trouxer null nesse join, serão os que poderão se tornar um usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um Linq com left join, assim irá trazer as pessoas que ainda não são usuários do seu sistema.

O trecho de código ficaria tipo assim:

```
pessoaDomain.GroupJoin(usuarioDomain,
                       pessoa => pessoa.Id,
                       usuario => usuario.IdPessoa,
                       (pessoa, usuario) => new
                       {
                            Pessoa = pessoa,
                            Usuario = usuario.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       })
           .Where(w => w.Usuario == null)
           .ToList();
```